# MySQL CONCAT add comma after

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling to get comma after value but this query is adding before value

```
ipaddress = CONCAT(IFNULL(ipaddress,''), ',$ipaddress')
```

The field's default value is `NULL`

Even I have tried this too but result is the same. Adding comma before not after.

```
ipaddress = CONCAT(IFNULL(ipaddress,''), ',', '$ipaddress')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CONCAT_WS` function. It inserts the separator between items, but ignores null items.

```
ipaddress = CONCAT_WS(',', ipaddress, '$ipaddress')
```

So if `ipaddress` is initially null, it will be ignored, so this won't put the separator between it and the added `$ipaddress` value.

However, the fact that you need to do this suggests that you're putting a comma-separated list into a SQL column. This is very poor design. You should normalize your schema, and move this to a separate table with a separate row for each value, and a foreign key relating back to this table.

Comment: Thanks for the resolution. I am adding IPs into one column because I am using it for Ratings. So for a single post, I will have many IPs. I believe row per IP will be too much for one post. I would like to know if there is any better approach to record IPs for ratings on post

Comment: If you have them all in one column, the column will be very big. And searching columns that are formatted like this is inefficient, it can't be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

If `ipaddress` is `NOT NULL` then the string is formatted correctly.

```
E.g. 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
```

In case where `ipaddress` `IS NULL`, the string will look like

```
,127.0.0.2
```

You can use MySQL's [TRIM](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php) function to fix this.

```
 TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM CONCAT(IFNULL(ipaddress,''), ',', '$ipaddress'))
 TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM CONCAT(IFNULL(NULL,''), ',', '127.0.0.2'))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I believe @Barmar solution is well optimized.

Comment: Yes, I agree :)